# Strapi deployment to Heroku

Tags: heroku, strapi

I am totally new on Strapi and Heroku. I am trying to deploy my app that is working well locally to Heroku but I am getting the following error:

*2020-06-15T09:56:29.114780+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-15T09:56:29.114Z] error Impossible to register the 'menus.menus' model.
2020-06-15T09:56:29.115672+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-15T09:56:29.115Z] error TimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?*

At the beginning I thought it was a problem connecting to the database, but in my local environment it work perfectly and connect with no issues.

I even upgraded my database to a paid version in case the connection is timing out.

I also follow some answers I found only about modifying my config/environment/production/database.json as follow:

```
{
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "connector": "bookshelf",
      "settings": {
        "client": "postgres",
        "host": "***.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
        "port": "5432",
        "database": "***",
        "username": "***",
        "password": "***",
        "ssl": { "rejectUnauthorized": false }
      },
      "options": {
        "debug": false,
        "acquireConnectionTimeout": 100000,
        "pool": {
          "min": 0,
          "max": 10,
          "createTimeoutMillis": 30000,
          "acquireTimeoutMillis": 600000,
          "idleTimeoutMillis": 20000,
          "reapIntervalMillis": 20000,
          "createRetryIntervalMillis": 200
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any other idea of what can it be?

When I run the develop locally I got a warn (but even this the app run anyway after):

*[2020-06-15T10:36:41.261Z] warn The bootstrap function is taking unusually long to execute (3500 miliseconds).
[2020-06-15T10:36:41.261Z] warn Make sure you call it?
[2020-06-15T10:36:42.476Z] warn The bootstrap function is taking unusually long to execute (3500 miliseconds).
[2020-06-15T10:36:42.476Z] warn Make sure you call it?*

Answer (score 0):

One simple first step option is to launch a strapi quickstart application on heroku. You can find this link here.. https://github.com/strapi/strapi

Relaunching with this method will provide you with a working, secure instance to begin development on.

Also note that heroku deploys strapi to production, so that you are not able to use the content-types editor, so it is recommended that you develop locally & test your app and use the heroku cli to update your deployment.